# Adding decimal numbers as strings in C

Tags: c

So I understand how to perform calculations on integers represented in strings and then printing the result in a string. But I'm lost on how to do the same thing with a decimal in the number represented in a string.

Here's how I did it with integers. This part of the code is adding together two integers:

```
int answer = 0;
char str1[100];
int count = 0;
int total = 0;  
int k = 0;
int diff = 0;

if (ele == ele2) {
    for (k = strlen(op1) - 1; k > -1; k--) {
        if ((strspn(operand, "+") == strlen(operand))) {
            answer = (op1[k] - '0') + (op2[k] - '0');
        } else if ((strspn(operand, "-") == strlen(operand))) {
            answer = (op1[k] - '0') - (op2[k] - '0');
        }

        total += (pow(10, count) * answer);
        count++;        
    }
    sprintf(str1, "%d", total);
    printf("Answer: %s ", str1);    
}
```

Output

```
// 12 + 14
Answer: 26 // Answer given as a string
```

Example

```
12.2 + 14.5 // Three strings
Answer: 16.7 // Answer as string
```

Current Attempt:

```
for (k = strlen(argv[1]) - 1; k > -1; k--) {
        if (argv[1][k] == '.') {
            dec = k;
        } else {
            answer = (argv[1][k] - '0') + (argv[3][k] - '0');
            total += (pow(10, count) * answer);
            count++;
        }


    }

    // needs to be converted to a long?
    // ele is the length of the operand
    total = total / pow(10, ele - dec); 

    sprintf(str1, "%d", total);
    printf("Answer: %s ", str1);
```

Comment: So... how did you do it for integers?

Comment: What do you mean by "integers as strings"? What do you mean by "decimal in the number string"? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And please include input and actual and expected output.

Comment: @George I'll re-edit my post with a snippet of my code, my apologies.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has been your approach? To me it seems a quite straight forward to do that - from that figuring out where you went wrong might be harder than actually doing this...

Comment: Just a thought, wouldn't it be easier to use e.g. `sscanf(input, "%d %c %d", &value1, &operator, &value2)` to parse the input into values and operator? Then it would be *very* easy to change to using floating-point values instead of having to parse the strings one digit at a time like you do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Except he might want to use this to add very large numbers which can't be done that way (there will on all standard conforming implementation exist integers too big to be possible to represent as an integral type).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ditto on skyking's comment. Plus, my assignment says to not use any scanf functions.

Comment: @Jasmine does your assignment say anything about `atof()`?

Comment: If it is as @skyking mentions, that you want to be able to handle extraordinary large numbers that can be handled by the native types in C (`long long` or `long double`) then I suggest you have a separate tokenizing phase, where you split the input into separate tokens. Creating an expression parser using a tokenized input is much easier than to handle strings like you do now, and tokenizing input is not very hard either.

Comment: @George no it doesn't mention anything about `atof()` nor have I learned it. But it also doesn't say that I CAN'T use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Will I still be able to get my answer printed out as a string if I use that method?

Comment: So it's an homework assignment? Consider this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You can print the result any way you want once you have it.

Comment: @skyking Yes, I'm aware of the homework assignment policy here on the site. I do my best to follow the rules.

Comment: What problem do you encounter with your approach?

Comment: @skyking when using my code for decimals, I get an incorrect number. Such as when calculating 12.2 + 12.2, I get a number something like 2364.

Comment: @Jasmine Well, as an option you can say something like `printf("The answer is: %f", (atof(op1)+atof(op2)))` <-- assuming the operand is '+'. Technically `atof()` returns a double, but just don't say anything :D

Comment: @George haha if only I do something as simple as that. However, the only acceptable type for the result is a string. Thank you though.

Comment: @Jasmine Sorry for obfuscating this a bit but I don't think it's a full answer, you can actually just convert back to a string: `sprintf(stringAnswer,"%f",(atof(op1)+atof(op2)));
 printf("The answer is: %s", stringAnswer);`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a simple algo to begin with (and assuming your adding integer funciton works fine).

A decimal number is basically two integers separated by ".".

- Identify the position of "." and grab the two sides of the integer as integerPart, decimalPart
- One caveat on getting the decimalPart is that the length of all the decimalParts should be same, if not, add "0"s in the suffix.
- Add the integerPart, add the decimalPart and handle the carryForwards in the decimalPart.

So,

```
12.2 + 14.95   
= (12 + 14)  (20 + 95)
= 26  115
= 26+1 15
= 27.15
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. My issue however, I'm printing out the whole answer at once as a string. And the way I'm doing that is adding each columns digit to the final result. So how do I get the decimal point in there? I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Why dont you call your function twice , get the output of both, handle everything and then print the answer. Do you really want to do it in one go? If yes, there are other approaches

Comment: I figured it'd be simpler if I did it in one go like I did with the rest of my work, but I'm open to other suggestions if there are better ways.

Comment: If you do it in one go, it would be like this:
a) Find the decimal point index for both the inputs.
b) Handle the decimal parts if both lengths are not equal (as stated in my answer)
c) Get the carry forward and then add it to the two integer parts.

This would be the same as the one I have suggested. In my case, you would have addTwoNumbers() which calls addTwoIntegers and addTwoDecimals().

Comment: a-c is what I attempted when I tried to code it. But I haven't tried separating the algorithm into three functions like you've mentioned, so I'll try that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty implementation: no parameter check, no deep test only an idea of how you should process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct
    {
            int total_digits;;
            int decimal_points;
            int *number;
    } NUMBER, *DECIMALNUMBER;

    DECIMALNUMBER initilize(char *str)
    {
            DECIMALNUMBER result = calloc(1, sizeof(NUMBER));
            int in_decimal = 0;
            char *s;
            int i;
            for (s = str; *s; s++)
            {
                    if (isdigit(*s))
                    {
                            result->total_digits++;
                            if (in_decimal)
                            {
                                    result -> decimal_points++;
                            }
                    }
                    else if (*s == '.')
                    {
                            in_decimal = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            return NULL;
                    }
            }
            result->number = calloc(result->decimal_points, sizeof(int));
            i=0;
            for (s = str; *s; s++)
            {
                    if (isdigit(*s))
                    {
                            result->number[i++] = (int)(*s - '0');
                    }
            }
    //      printf("result->total_digits is %d\n",result->total_digits);
    //      printf("result->decimal_points is %d\n",result->decimal_points);
    //      printf("result is %d\n",result->number[--i]);
    //      printf("result is %d\n",result->number[--i]);
    //      printf("result is %d\n",result->number[--i]);
            return result;
        }

    void print_number(DECIMALNUMBER p)
    {
            int i;
            for (i=0; i<p->total_digits; i++)
            {
                    if (i==p->total_digits - p->decimal_points) {
                            printf(".");
                    }

                    printf("%d", p->number[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

    DECIMALNUMBER sum(DECIMALNUMBER a, DECIMALNUMBER b)
    {
            int max_decimals =  a->decimal_points>b->decimal_points ? a->decimal_points : b->decimal_points;

            int max_digits_count = a->total_digits>b->total_digits ? a->total_digits : b->total_digits;
            DECIMALNUMBER result = calloc(1, sizeof(NUMBER));
            result->total_digits = max_digits_count;
            result->decimal_points = max_decimals;
            result->number = calloc(max_digits_count, sizeof(int));

            int i1 = a->total_digits-1;
            int i2 = b->total_digits-1;
            int i3 = result->total_digits-1;
            int remainder = 0;
            int summed;
            while (i1 >= 0 || i2 >=0)
            {
                    int aa = i1 < 0 ? 0 : a->number[i1];
                    int bb = i2 < 0 ? 0 : b->number[i2];
                    summed = aa + bb + remainder;
                    result->number[i3] = summed % 10;
                    remainder = summed / 10;
                    i1--;
                    i2--;
                    i3--;
            }
            return result;
    }

    int main()
    {
            DECIMALNUMBER a = initilize("12.2");
            DECIMALNUMBER b = initilize("16.7");

            print_number(a);
            print_number(b);

            DECIMALNUMBER c = sum (a,b);
            print_number(c);

            return 0;
    }
```